# Algebraic characterization of being $P_n$-free.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Is there an algebraic way to determine from the adjacency matrix $A$ of a simple graph $G$, whether $G$ contains an induced path of fixed length $n$? I am particularly interested in the case $n=6$.

If there is no characterization, I would also be interested in (possibly strict) sufficient conditions on $A$, which forces $G$ to contain an induced $P_n$ (resp. $P_6$).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a characterization of graphs with no induced $P_4$, but I do not recall seeing any algebraic proof of the characterization. I think problems with induced paths get more difficult as $n$ increases, and so I suspect strongly the answer to your first question is "no".

Comment: @ChrisGodsil: Thank you for your assessment, but I do not seek for an algebraic proof of a characterization, but rather for an algebraic characterization (involving e.g. eigenvalues, powers of the adjacency matrix etc.).